# How to make stream simpler than current stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Currently my code is this long. I know it's possible to make this much shorter but can't seem to figure it out.

```
Employee[] fullTimeEmployees = employees.stream().filter((Employee e) -> {
            for (Project project : e.getAssignedProjects()) {
                int hoursWorked = project.getCommittedHoursPerDay().get(e);
                if (hoursWorked >= 8)
                    return true ;
            }
            return false ;
        }).toArray(Employee[] :: new);
        
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fullTimeEmployees));
```

I've tried using flatmap but didn't succes with it.

My code with flatmap was:

```
List<Project> test = employees.stream().flatMap(employee -> employee.getAssignedProjects().stream()
           .filter(project -> project.getCommittedHoursPerDay().get(employee) >= 8))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Would appreciate any help!

edit:

This is the for loop that I tried to make a stream of:

```
        for (Employee employee : employees) {
            for (Project project : employee.getAssignedProjects()) {
                int hoursWorked = project.getCommittedHoursPerDay().get(employee);
                if (hoursWorked >= 8)
                    if (!fullTimeEmployees.contains(employee))
                        fullTimeEmployees.add(employee);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following filter is simpler. There's no need to use `flatMap`. Just use `anyMatch` on the `Stream` of an `Employee`'s assigned projects.

```
Employee[] fullTimeEmployees = 
    employees.stream()
             .filter(e -> e.getAssignedProjects()
                           .stream()
                           .anyMatch(p -> p.getCommittedHoursPerDay().get(e) >= 8))
             .toArray(Employee[] :: new);
```